# Cursor in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I have ***ORACLE*** class **airport_t** that has data fields for

```
Rank,
Airport,
Location,
Country,
Code_IATA,
Code_ICAO,
Total_passenger,
Rank_change,
Percent_Change
```

I created table **AIRPORTS2017OO** that has one single column **AIRPORT**, which can store an object of type **airport_t**. I have 50 rows of data in **Airport2017** table which I to insert into **airport** column of table **AIRPORTS2017OO** using cursor.

I am able to iterate through **airports2017** table through cursor given below, but I do not know how to insert data into **AIRPORTS2017OO** table.

Here is my solution of getting all info from **airports2017** table

```
DECLARE
   rank1        NUMBER;
   airports1    VARCHAR2 (80);
   location1    VARCHAR (40);
   country1     VARCHAR (30);
   iata1        VARCHAR (3);
   icao1        VARCHAR (4);
   total_pass   NUMBER;
   rank_c       NUMBER;
   p_change     NUMBER;

   CURSOR display
   IS
      SELECT * FROM airports2017;
BEGIN
   OPEN display;

   LOOP
      FETCH display
         INTO rank1,
              airports1,
              location1,
              country1,
              iata1,
              icao1,
              total_pass,
              rank_c,
              p_change;

      IF display%FOUND
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (airports1);
      ELSE
         EXIT;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE display;
END;
/
```

Comment: Are you in control of the database design for this? Because if I were you, instead of storing the data in the airport_t object and inserting that into a column of a table, I would create a new table that has a foreign key back to the main table, and then insert the data into the new table. Much, much easier to query things that way.

Comment: Hey, no I cannot control the design. Have to stick to the question given.

Answer (score 1):

You do know that you can do:

```
INSERT INTO AIRPORTS2017OO select * from airports2017;
```

instead of all this cursor code right?

Anyway here's how to do it:

```
DECLARE    
   a_data ARRAY;
   CURSOR display
   IS
      SELECT * FROM airports2017;
BEGIN
   OPEN display;

   LOOP
      FETCH display BULK COLLECT INTO a_data;

      FORALL i IN 1..a_data.COUNT
         INSERT INTO AIRPORTS2017OO VALUES a_data(i);

      IF display%FOUND
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (airports1);
      ELSE
         EXIT;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE display;
END;
/
```

Comment: Hi, I tried running this, it's showing multiple errors. Can you please have a look at it? And for this solution INSERT INTO AIRPORTS2017OO select * from airports2017; the error is 'too many values.'

Comment: Is the structure of AIRPORTS2017OO the same as airports2017?  otherwise do "create table AIRPORTS2017OO as select * from airports2017"

Comment: Better yet, list the columns you're inserting into and selecting from, e.g. `insert into airports2017oo (col1, col2, ...) select cola, colb, ... from airports2017;`